# What's the Accept-Ranges Header working principle?

Tags: browser, http, range

What's the Accept-Ranges Header working principle?

we know `Accept-Ranges: bytes` means the URL can be request by ranges.

I have several questions about it:

1. When Server return the URL HTTP response, if the URL is a large file, will or will not return partial data of it in the HTTP response?
2. When browser get the response Accept-Ranges, will it fetch the whole data of the file automatically?